# How Do I sort files based on both date time in Powershell ? [sort files with same time but different dates]

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have multiple files in a directory created at the same time but on different dates.

`$files = Get-ChildItem C:\File*.txt | Sort-Object { $_.CreationTime } | Select-Object Name`

`$files[0]` doesn't seem to be picking the oldest file(File1) that was created. Which property of Sort-Object can I use to sort files based on both date and time?

Example :

```
File1_20220107 123001 AM.txt
File2_20220109 123001 AM.txt
File3_20220110 123001 AM.txt
```

Comment: Are you trying to sort them by the timestamp on their names or by the actual `CreationTime` property of the files?

Comment: Actual CreationTime. @SantiagoSquarzon

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't? Note that `CreationTime` is not visible by default, you might be looking at `LastWriteTime` which could be causing confusion. You can also just do `| Sort-Object CreationTime` there is no need for a scriptblock.

Comment: The rest of the script processes that particular file and files[0] gives incorrect file

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is, sorting by `CreationTime` is totally possible, I have a feeling you want to sort the files by the Date in their names.

Answer (score 4):

Building on [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon)'s helpful comments:

- Sorting by the `.CreationTime` property of the [`[System.IO.FileInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances that [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) outputs works fine and relies on the *file-system metadata* for the timestamp of each file's creation.
- A *string representation* of a (creation) date embedded in a file's *name* may or may not reflect the file's actual creation timestamp (and even if it did, it wouldn't be an *exact* match, given that the file-system-maintained timestamps have *sub*-second granularity.

**To sort by actual `.CreationTime`**, as reported by the file-system, you can use the following simplified version of your own attempt, given that there's no need for a *script block* (`{ ... }`) to reference the `.CreationTime` property:

```sh
Get-ChildItem C:\File*.txt | Sort-Object CreationTime | Select-Object Name
```

**To sort by the timestamp string embedded in your file names**:

```sh
Get-ChildItem C:\File*.txt | 
  Sort-Object {
    [datetime] (
      $_.BaseName -replace '^.+_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2}) (\d{2})(\d{2})', '$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:'
    ) 
  } | 
    Select-Object Name
```